# How to get a major mode to open full screen

Tags: elisp, window, major-mode, magit

I'd like magit to default to a large buffer instead of one that is half the size of the available space. Even better would be a way to wrap the call to a major mode to make this happen when opening any major mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about applying this in general but magit has a configuration variable for this, `magit-status-buffer-switch-function`. By default it is set to `pop-to-buffer` which prefers to open an alternate buffer, ie `other-window` or split screen and `other-window`. However, if you customize the value to `switch-to-buffer` it will swap out the current buffer for `magit-status`. Throw the following in your init file and it should open it in the current window:

```
(setq magit-status-buffer-switch-function 'switch-to-buffer)
```

Edit: It appears the general solution to this problem may be encoded in the documentation for [`display-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html#Choosing-Window), specifically [Choosing Window](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window-Options.html#Choosing-Window-Options) and [Display Action Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html#Display-Action-Functions).

Answer (score 3):

How about [fullframe](https://github.com/tomterl/fullframe) ?

From their docs:

```
;;; Open magit-status in a single window in fullscreen
(require 'fullframe)
(fullframe magit-status magit-mode-quit-window nil)
```

Comment: This looks like a nice package. It'd be great to add a few words about it. Does it just make the command full screen, or does it also revert to the previous configuration when quitting?

Comment: Well, it's documented on their github README. You pass in a function and an 'exit function'. In this example when you quit the magit-status window, it runs magit-mode-quit-window.

Comment: actually, I asked because the Readme does _not_ say what the exit-command is used for. :-)

Comment: Agreed, it's unclear. I've filed a [patch](https://github.com/tomterl/fullframe/pull/18).

Comment: Just merged the patch...

Comment: Sorry @Malabarba. I guess it made sense to me. Meanwhile, sanityinc posted a more complete answer below. And, of course, I found fullframe by reading his .emacs configs. So he wins!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples using [fullframe](https://github.com/tomterl/fullframe), lifted straight from my emacs config:

```
(eval-after-load 'package
  '(fullframe list-packages quit-window))

(eval-after-load 'magit
  '(fullframe magit-status magit-mode-quit-window))

(eval-after-load 'ibuffer
  '(fullframe ibuffer ibuffer-quit))
```

The first parameter for `fullframe` is any command which creates and switches to a new window, and the second is a function which is called when that window is quit - either the command the user uses to quit the window, or a command which is called in the course of the window being quit.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically with regards to Magit and `magit-status`, the following should do the trick for you:  [Magit Status Fullscreen](http://whattheemacsd.com/setup-magit.el-01.html) from Magnar Sveen's What the .emacs.d!? blog.

```
;; full screen magit-status
(defadvice magit-status (around magit-fullscreen activate)
  (window-configuration-to-register :magit-fullscreen)
  ad-do-it
  (delete-other-windows))

;; restore previously hidden windows
(defadvice magit-quit-window (around magit-restore-screen activate)  
  ad-do-it
  (jump-to-register :magit-fullscreen))
```

Updated with Brad Wright's comment with regards to restoring previous view.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I currently use.

```
(defadvice magit-status (around magit-fullscreen activate)
  (window-configuration-to-register :magit-fullscreen)
  ad-do-it
  (delete-other-windows)) 

 (defun custom-kill-buffers (regexp)
  "Kill buffers matching REGEXP without asking for confirmation."
  (interactive "sKill buffers matching this regular expression: ")
  (flet ((kill-buffer-ask (buffer) (kill-buffer buffer)))
    (kill-matching-buffers regexp)))

(defun magit-quit-session ()
  "Restores the previous window configuration and kills the magit buffer"
  (interactive)
  (custom-kill-buffers "^\\*magit")
  (jump-to-register :magit-fullscreen))

(define-key magit-status-mode-map (kbd "q") 'magit-quit-session)
```

I customized the solution explained on [whattheemacsd.com](http://whattheemacsd.com/setup-magit.el-01.html): I close every magit buffer when I press "q".